# Jar not being added to classpath - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm having trouble adding the Parse library to my project.  I have the Parse jar in a folder called libs.  The Gradle sync completes successfully, but the library doesn't show up under "External Libraries."

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.qrazhan.food"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/Parse-1.7.0.jar')
}
```

I'm using the default Gradle wrapper included with Android Studio.

EDIT: The gradle build finishes successfully without error, but I still cannot use the library.  Here is a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0a3eydaj96nfg7/Screenshot%202014-10-03%2011.00.46.png?dl=0

Comment: Invalidate Caches and restart

Comment: How do I invalidate the cache?

Comment: Menu > File > Invalidate Caches

Comment: Did that, still doesn't work. :(

Comment: dependencies {
    runtime files('libs/Parse.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse.jar')
}

Comment: Hmm... now i'm getting:
Error:(22, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'runtime()'!

Comment: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies

Comment: I did some Googling on the unsupported method error and found that you need to use the "java" plugin.  But, the "java" plugin is incompatible with the android plugin.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: [Check Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library) ... Maybe it helps

Answer (score 1):

Does the library file name really starts with a capital?

Otherwise try

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

instead of enumerating all jar files.

Comment: I've tried this and it still doesn't work.  The Gradle build finishes without error, yet I still can't use any of the classes in the library.  Maybe [this will help?](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0a3eydaj96nfg7/Screenshot%202014-10-03%2011.00.46.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this.  I have no idea what went wrong with Android Studio.  I had to make a new project.  This time, Android Studio automatically made the libs folder for me and I was able to copy in the JAR and right-click -> "Add as Library"